# Munin's load plugin does not appear

Tags: monitoring, munin, load-average

I just did a fresh install of Munin 2.0.6-4 on a Debian 7.1 server from the debian repositories. The "load" plugin appears as loaded:

```
# munin-node-configure | grep load
load                       | yes  |                                        
vserver_loadavg            | no   |
```

However, I can't see any "Load average" graph. For all I know, the load plugin seems to be working:

```
# munin-run load config
graph_title Load average
graph_args --base 1000 -l 0
graph_vlabel load
graph_scale no
graph_category system
load.label load
graph_info The load average of the machine describes how many processes are in the run-queue (scheduled to run "immediately").
load.info 5 minute load average

# munin-run load 
load.value 0.05
```

I have no idea how to debug this any further.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see at least the initial page without HTTP errors? I would recommend this:

Didn't you try to run the plugin/script or other munin command under different user than munin?!? Do the default web servers users apache/apache2 have access to these files?

It could have happened that required files (rrd, html, graphs) are not owned by munin user or that they don't have correct permissions set and so they can't be processed under munin user or accessed by web server process. The rrd databases are stored in /var/lib/munin while the html in /var/www/munin. Check all these directories and their ownership, groups and permissions.

If the above is set properly you can try to debug it further:

- Restart the **munin-node** service to activate any new plugin you configured.
- try to run **munin-update** command by hand under munin user:

  ```
  su - munin -c "PATH_TO/munin-update --debug --nofork --stdout \
                                      --host YOUR_HOST --service load"
  ```

This command is scheduled to be run via cron to  fetch data from configured munin nodes (munin-node process) and to store it to the rrd database(s). The command above will print all the messages to your screen. Can you see any related line to the load plugin?

```
Aug 23 15:41:51 - [6846] Updating /var/lib/munin/dom.com/foo.dom.com-df-load.rrd with 0.2
```

If so, the rrd database for this plugin is updated correctly and the problem may be with your web server.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody stumbling on this as well (and you did actually restart munin-node after adding the plugins):

if `echo -e "list\nquit" | nc 127.0.0.1 4949` doesn't show your plugin. it seems starting with debian buster (munin-node 2.0.49-1) you need to copy plugins to `/usr/share/munin/plugins` for them to be listed. i liked to have a different local dir with plugins from contrib and that doesn't work anymore. this worked fine with debian strech (munin-node 2.0.33-1).

Comment: Thanks for this! I was debugging my setup for half an hour before deciding to google the problem.It would have been nice is this was mentioned in NEWS.Debian... The stupid thing is that "munin-run pluginname" works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs in the client and in the server. Maybe there is something nasty. Did you restart munin-node after adding "load" plugin ?